# how to add logo in heading of extent report 2.41.2 selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I want to add image in my extent report. I tried with the below code in my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="MYhoenixTestExecution" verbose="1" >
<!-- <listeners>

<listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />

<listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />

</listeners> -->

<listeners>
        <listener class-name="phoenix.report.ExtentReporterNG" />
    </listeners>

<reportHeadline>Automation Report <image id="image-zoom">
        <![CDATA[   
        <img src='C:\CATS\logo.png'/>
        ]]>
    </image></reportHeadline>
<image id="image-zoom">
        <![CDATA[   
        <img src='C:\CATS\logo.png'/>
        ]]>
    </image>

<test name="Myphoenix_Login TC" >
    <classes>
      <class name="phoenix.testcases.Login_TC"/>
     </classes>
 </test>
```

But still unable to add logo. Please suggest.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps that capability is only available in the commercial version?  You should also probably consider updating to the 3.x community version.

Comment: There are tons of article available on Internet on how to do this, but for anyone who is still looking for this: https://github.com/appumistri/CustomizedExtentReport check this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done that with ver3.1.2

This is my extent-config.xml below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <extentreports>
<configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>dark</theme>

    <!-- document encoding -->
    <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
    <!-- defaults to https -->
    <protocol>https</protocol>

    <!-- title of the document -->
    <documentTitle>TRAX</documentTitle>

    <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
    <reportName>
    <![CDATA[
            <img src='.//myCompanyLogo.svg' />
        ]]>              
    </reportName>


    <!-- location of charts in the test view -->
    <!-- top, bottom -->
    <testViewChartLocation>bottom</testViewChartLocation>

    <!-- custom javascript -->
    <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {

            });
        ]]>
    </scripts>

    <!-- custom styles -->
    <styles>
        <![CDATA[
            .report-name { padding-left: 10px; } .report-name > img { float: 
      left;height: 90%;margin-left: 30px;margin-top: 2px;width: auto; }
        ]]>
    </styles>
</configuration>
</extentreports>
```

Please note that you have to take care of the location of the image. I have put the company logo in the Logo folder and copy it in the Reports folder before populating the html.report.